# Comparing integer in record with another record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Really stuck on this so all advice is gratefully received..

I've got a table with the following fields: City(Varchar), Year (Int), Population (Int)

I desperately need some SQL that will compare every city's population in one year with that of the previous (there are 20 cities in total). This means checking one record with another. Thanks in advance for any words of wisdom.

[Example City record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEHbL.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: This is of very low quality and is unclear. If you won't respond to any comments, then so be it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You coul use a self join

```
      select  a.City
            , a.popolation population_2019
            , b.population population_2020
            , a.popolation -  b.population diff
      from my_table a
      inner join my_table b on a.city  = b.city 
        and a.year = 2019
            b.year= 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

I slightly changed @scaisEdge to show all cities and years in a list. It is suitable if you need data for the chart, for example.

```sql
      SELECT a.City, a.Year,
             a.Population population,
             b.Population previous_population,
             a.Population - b.Population AS diff
      FROM city_data AS a
      JOIN city_data AS b ON a.City = b.City AND a.year = b.year + 1
      ORDER BY a.City, a.Year
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kR9QDGG18D1abz3f6UdUvc/2